# Gatsby keeps messing up the Index.html file during "gatsby develop." Any way to turn this off?

Tags: html, reactjs, gatsby

While working on my Gatsby site, I imported Semantic UI CDN through index.html under the public folders. It worked exactly as it should when I rendered it. However, when I closed down the dev server and relaunched it, the modifications I made to the html file were scraped. It appears that Gatsby does this on default. Is there a way to disable this behavior?

I've tried modifying the html file. After wrapping and prettiefying the code.

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.4.1/semantic.min.css">`

Yep, totally valid code that works until Gatsby changes index.html upon build.

Any changes I make to the index.html should stay that way, especially if they are completely valid and don't break the program. I'm sure there's another way to implement Semantic, but this one is pretty effortless since I just pop over the link and use it. I'm using another CSS library that I prefer and will probably fork and just add the elements that it's "missing." But for now I just need to finish this project and want to know if anyone understands how and why Gatsby modifies the HTML index and if there's a way to turn this off. Since again, it doesn't break the site.

Comment: webpack is responsible for hot reloading, altering, and repackaging files. I think you might be able to create a rule or custom config to prevent alteration of the `index.html`. But then you won't get hot reloading for your `index.html`. But I think this approach is wrong. A better way would be to inject your cdn code snippet into the `index.html` everytime it hot reloads. I have never done this so don't ask me how to do this.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I'll be able to look into it and compare Gatsby starter with Create React App. Since I do the same thing in React and never have issues with the index.html.

Comment: https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/custom-html/

Comment: Thanks @ksav that's what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

gatsbyjs.org/docs/custom-html

This was resolved by user [ksav](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5385381/ksav) in the comments above.